# Редактор Atom - помогите подключить компилятор

Tags: компилятор, atom

Есть некий язык, некий компилятор (назовем их так). Хочется редактировать исходник в редакторе, потом из редактора запускать компилятор, но самое главное - по выдаче компилятора показывать в редакторе строчки с ошибками.
Поискал информацию - вроде это умеет редактор Atom, но вот никакого описания как его обучить этому не нашел. Предлагают только готовые плагины для конкретных языков, а мне нужно понять, как это делать самому.

Comment: IMHO, ответ очевидный: раз нет плагина для вашего языка - его нужно написать самостоятельно. Как? Посмотрите в любом аналогичном плагине, благо все они с исходниками.